# I'm good vs I'm a good man

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

I know "I'm good "means I feel good /I'm fine which is the answer of question "How are you/How do you feel". Am I right?

Comment: Sometimes "I'm good is used in a different way. For example: "would you like another glass of water?" No, thank you, I'm good.

Answer (score 1):

> "I'm good"

- refers to the well-being of the person - like you said: I feel good, I'm fine;
- gives information about **how** are you;
- it can have specific meaning: I do not need anything, everything is fine.

Example by @anuk (thanks):

```
Do you need some water?
No, I am good, thanks.
```

---

> "I'm a good man"

- means that you do good deeds, you are kind, polite, charitable...
- gives information about **what** you do;

---

There is a **very** specific / special context, where "I'm good" **gets** (but **does not have** in itself) the meaning of "I'm a good man":

```
Are you a good man or a bad man?
I am good.
```

He "I am good" means "I am a good man" only because of the speech trick, of not repeating some of the words in the question.

Comment: Please avoid using code formatting for emphasis or quotes. It's never correct, it looks ugly, and it makes things more confusing for screen readers etc.

Comment: I understand your concern, especially about screen readers (I did not have them in mind, sorry). But the possibility to add emphasis was provided for exactly this purpose. I agree, if everything is emphasized, and all types of emphasis are used randomly, that's really ugly. Maybe you help me with this, please? How should I proceed? Just dumping words seems "under-optimized", when emphasis is available. Thank you.

Comment: You can use bold or italics for emphasis, not code formatting. (You're already correctly using block quotes when they fit, so that's fine.) In general, though, I'd suggest relying on the subtle offset effect of standard quote punctuation to do the job; it's only when there's something really unusual that you need to emphasize anything. (A particular word that could easily be misread, for example, and that's important to the answer.)

Comment: Then we surely have different understandings about "emphasize". Bold and italic are methods to emphasize, from my point of view :) I may guess that you refer specifically to the reversed single quotes?

Comment: @virolino I see nothing wrong with the use of code formatting for short fragments of text like this. (I use code formatting for one or two words at times too—although not for this exact situation.) It's up to you if you want to rollback this edit. (I don't personally believe it was a warranted edit in this case.) However, it's not what would commonly be used here. Personally, I would use "I'm **good**" and "I'm **a good man**." But that's subjective. Different people format these things differently.

Comment: @virolino: I thought I was pretty clear that I was talking only about *using backticks* for emphasis. See [this discussion on meta for more on the ill-suitedness of code formatting for ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/should-backticks-be-used-or-quotation-marks-while-formatting).

Comment: Now it is clear. I did not assimilate all proper vocabulary yet. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: How can it be posible, I'm good= I' a good man? If I'm good (meaning fine that means I feel fine or I'm happy) means I'm a good man, it confuses me by introducing a critical clue. A man who isn't a good man may be happy/ feel good now. I mean I'm good= I'm fine or I feel happy, (not a good man, as it's the answer of question like Who are  you). Am I right? Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea what you say. I explained that they are different.